# CSV edit without changing delimiter and enclosure

Tags: csv

I've a CSV file with

```
 delimiter = |
 enclosure = "
```

When I open the CSV file with MS EXCEL to add a row, it adds a new row with no enclosure and changes the delimiter to comma.

What can I do to add / update file with out changing the delimiter??

Comment: If you're opening the file with MS Excel, and updating it with MS Excel, and it's MS Excel that's changing the delimiter and enclosure, then what has this got to do with PHP?

Comment: Open it in Notepad and edit it there instead.  It won't damage your file as it is already plain text.

Comment: Mark, Removed PHP, Thanks for the advise..

Comment: Durbnpoisn, Yes thats too much work for long-term. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not found any solid solution for this problem. But I have resolved this issue by doing following.

```
On import file change delimiter to comma usual CSV formate. 
Change all the commas in data to HTML Entity &#44;
```

Please advise me if there is anything better then this.